# Microsoft Graph NextLink Not Working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm having problems using the server-side paging, utilizing the `@odata.nextlink` to fetch the next page of data from Microsoft Graph, based on the information in [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters). I'm using raw GETs, with the authorization token set in the header (ie, I'm not using a language API, I'm trying this from Powershell using curl). I've scrubbed sensitive data from the following snippets, replacing them with x's, but hopefully the problematic info comes across.

For the first GET, I query with

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/b!Gxxxxx-xxxxxxge/root:/ReallyBigFolder:/children?top=200
```

and I get a response with 200 items, as expected. The `@odata.nextlink` field in this response is

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/b!Gxxxxx-xxxxxxge/root/children?top=200&$skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_SortBehavior%3d0%26p_FileLeafRef%3d279%252ezip%26p_ID%3d208%26p_FileDirRef%3dMaintenance%2520Department%252fReallyBigFolder%26RootFolder%3dMaintenance%2520Department%252fReallyBigFolder
```

For the examples in the Microsoft Graph documentation linked above, the `$skiptoken=...` part has random-looking numbers, but mine has `$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&etc`. Perhaps the API has changed the response since the documentation was written, or mine is completely incorrect.

My understanding from the documentation is that I should be able to use this URL as an opaque value, and GET it from the Graph API (with auth token of course) without modification. However, when I do this, the response is

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#drives('b%21Gxxxxx-xxxxxxge')/root/children","value":[]}
```

Where I'm expecting to get another 200 files listed, there are no files returned at all, and it appears the path is gone, pointing to the root rather than the subfolder like it should have been.

I've also tried this in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) with both the `/beta` and `/v1.0` endpoints, and it fails in the same way there as well.

Where am I going wrong?

**Edit with details for debugging**: Note: Graph Explorer doesn't seem to display the Date field from headers, so I'm using Postman Chrome Plugin for these values.

First GET request is to

```
beta/drives/b!xxx-xxxge/root:/Really%20Big%20Folder/ReallyBigFolder:/children
```

With response headers

```
Cache-Control →private
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Type →application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
Date →Fri, 26 May 2017 19:07:54 GMT
Duration →2033.3889
OData-Version →4.0
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Vary →Accept-Encoding
client-request-id →6faf5d1d-a291-410a-b269-f4667187d7cb
request-id →6faf5d1d-a291-410a-b269-f4667187d7cb
x-ms-ags-diagnostic →{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Central US","Slice":"SliceB","ScaleUnit":"002","Host":"AGSFE_IN_11","ADSiteName":"CHI"}}
```

and nextLink (obfuscated slightly for security)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/b!xxx-xxxge/root/children?$skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_SortBehavior%3d0%26p_FileLeafRef%3d279%252ezip%26p_ID%3d208%26p_FileDirRef%3dGSH%2520Test%252fMaintenance%2520Department%252fReally%2520Big%2520Folder%252fReallyBigFolder%26RootFolder%3d%252fGSH%2520Test%252fMaintenance%2520Department%252fReally%2520Big%2520Folder%252fReallyBigFolder
```

Following the nextLink produces headers (unchanged headers omitted):

```
Date →Fri, 26 May 2017 19:15:17 GMT
Duration →512.9537
client-request-id →6ba61712-a423-4bc8-9376-cc62bf854329
request-id →6ba61712-a423-4bc8-9376-cc62bf854329
x-ms-ags-diagnostic →{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Central US","Slice":"SliceA","ScaleUnit":"001","Host":"AGSFE_IN_7","ADSiteName":"CHI"}}
```

and resulting body:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#drives('b%21xxxx-xxxxge')/root/children",
  "value": []
}
```

Comment: Can you include the value of the "Request-ID" header and "Date" headers on the responses you're getting from MS Graph? That will enable us to take a look at the logs and see what's going on here.

Comment: @RyanGregg Header information included in an edit to the question.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I've been able to confirm there is a bug in how nextLink is returned for queries to the /drives/ path. Queries to /me/drive work normally. We're working on a fix.

Comment: @RyanGregg Hi, Can I check if the fix is up? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the nextLink should be an opaque URL that returns you the next set of results.  The format of that string may change over time, so you should not try to parse or otherwise interpret the string, but the usage should be the same.

The response that you are getting back is consistent with an empty result -- meaning that there are no additional files to list.

How many results do you have in ReallyBigFolder?  What happens if you set top to a different value (say, 5? 1000?)

Note that the @odata.context describes the result, but is not necessarily the same as the request URL. Is the @odata.context that you get back from nextLink different than that you got back from the initial request?  It should be the same...

Comment: There are 450 files in that folder, created for testing in PS script by "touch"ing file names in a loop, so they are essentially 0 byte files, but lots of them. If I do top=500, then I get all 450 files. If I do top=5, I get 5 results, then try to follow the nextLink, then I get empty set. The @odata.context in nextLink results matches that in the original query results.

Comment: There appears to be some confusion between "server-side paging" and "client-side paging".  Client side paging is the ability for a client to ask for a specific range of pages.  For example, top=200 gets the first 200 results.  top=200&skip=200 would get results 201-400.  So you should be able to get the next 200 files by using:

Comment: ... the URL:
http://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/b!Gxxxxx-xxxxxxge/root:/ReallyBigFolder:/children?top=200&skip=200.

NextLinks are used when the *server* decides to return a subset of the result. I'm not sure why you're getting a nextLink since you got all 200 records you requested (top=200); typically it would only be returned if you got less than the requested number of records (say, the first 100), in which case the nextlink would return (up to) the remaining 100. So it's arguably correct for the nextlink to return no records, but strange that it's included at all.

Does that help?

Comment: That difference between client- and server-side paging makes sense, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. If I do `/children?top=200&skip=200` then I end up getting the original files 1-200, not 201-400 as expected. I also tried ordering `/children?orderby=name&top=200&skip=200` and that still returns the first 200 files. If I let the server do paging, by just getting `/children` without any query parameters, the nextLink is the same as before, and returns an empty result set again.

Comment: This feels like a service bug. The value returned from @odata.nextLink should be used the way you are describing. We don't support the &skip= parameter for files enumerating, so as you are seeing that parameter is just ignored and you get back the original 200 items again. I'm investigating.

Comment: As @RyanGregg notes, there is currently a bug in the /drives/ nextLink code. Once that bug is fixed, this answer will be correct, so I'm marking it as the accepted answer.